# EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, when trying to copy one file to another directory using fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-fs

Im trying to copy one of my files from one directory into another directory

```
.then((answers) => {
        //installing dependencies in specified directory
        try{
            console.log(answers.dependencies)
            //answers.dependencies
            let dest = "/Users/[name]/Code/test"
            let copyingFile = fs.copyFile('/Users/[name]/Code/boilerplate/EZBOILERPLATE/testFile.js', "/Users/[name]/Code/test")
        } catch(error) {
            console.log("Error when copying file: ", error )
        }
        console.log("file coppied". copyingFile)
        
    })
}
```

but whenever I try to run the program I get this error in javascript

```
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, copyfile '/Users/[name]/Code/boilerplate/EZBOILERPLATE/testFile.js' -> '/Users/[name]/Code/test'] {
  errno: -21,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'copyfile',
  path: '/Users/[name]/Code/boilerplate/EZBOILERPLATE/testFile.js',
  dest: '/Users/[name]/Code/test'
}
```

Comment: The destination has to be a name for the actual file, not a directory.

Comment: it still doesnt work, how would I copy a file from one directory into another file? Doesn't it have to copy one file into a directory

Comment: If "/Users/[name]/Code/test" is a directory, you have to change the path to "/Users/[name]/Code/test/testFile.js"

Comment: Basically `.copyFile()` does not work like the `cp` command from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [fs.copyFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscopyfilesrc-dest-mode-callback) then you need to specify the filename on the destination and use a callback to check for errors like so:

```js
fs.copyFile(
'/Users/[name]/Code/boilerplate/EZBOILERPLATE/testFile.js',
'/Users/[name]/Code/test/testFile.js', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    //Handle error
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the second argument to the `copyFile` function must be the destination file path (not the path to a directory).

If you plan to copy more than one file to a destination directory, you can abstract the file path manipulation using a function, for example:

`copy_to_dir.mjs`:

```js
import { copyFile } from "node:fs/promises";
import { basename, join } from "node:path";

export function copyToDir(srcFilePath, destDirPath, mode) {
  const destFilePath = join(destDirPath, basename(srcFilePath));
  return copyFile(srcFilePath, destFilePath, mode);
}
```

> Ref: [`fsPromises.copyFile`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/fs.html#fspromisescopyfilesrc-dest-mode), [`path.basename`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/path.html#pathbasenamepath-suffix), [`path.join`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/path.html#pathjoinpaths)

Then you can use the function with the same arguments in your original code:

```js
import { copyToDir } from "./copy_to_dir.mjs";

await copyToDir(
  "/Users/[name]/Code/boilerplate/EZBOILERPLATE/testFile.js",
  "/Users/[name]/Code/test",
);
```

and the file will be copied to `/Users/[name]/Code/test/testFile.js`.

---

[TypeScript code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/PQgEB4CcFMDNpgOwMbVAFwJ4AdoGcBeAIkQHsATaI0YAPgCh6BLAW21MnVAG9RlTsmAGJMANmgC+oWJFItQJCtABcsPMGyyWTPPiIBuZmw5deAIwCGuxBZbQANKABWpJolBSZchWUrLsFugAFgaM0AAe7JzSAK4o6Eyk7vyCACqkACJMkAAU9KCgeJDIIuIACoFByoXokG4A5vb5oJR46FmQFcHVbXWIjc0sSgD81YgxLGYIoAA+oHGUsG7Q5E0AlNVlWjrQ4ABuruS0PM38iG0t+Oil0F1BoATOrog5re3Zd46W1rbQOUUlMS3SprNaGAowdAxSDJATCIH-Yo3T6XNrIyqOIaUMH0CT0IA)